# Unity change scene near an object when key press down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a project for my school where i have to do a museum. I wanna do when the player is near a painting or a statue, for example, it shows a message to press a key. When the player press that key it should change the scene.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keypress and proximity sensor sound like two separate problems to me. Look into sphere colliders for the proximity

Answer (score 2):

You can make a **trigger** to the image (that is on the place next to the image) that [on trigger stay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) will [show the text using unity GUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTkqHGi-sPA) and when the player press the key you can use [get key down](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

and then change the scene using this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
.
.
.
.
    public void ChagneScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene 2");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
.
.
.

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) {  
    // A letter key pressed, change to other keycode for other buttons
    // https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html


    SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneToLoad", LoadSceneMode.Single);     // this will load at next update
    // LoadSceneMode.Single replces current scene with this one
    // LoadSceneMode.Additive draws new scene on top of this one


}
```

Comment: You just posted the same answer as I did an hour after me, look before you post.

Comment: There were no posts when I posted, the timestamps both say 8 hours ago, if I posted an hour later, mine would say 7 hours ago.